# redirect to a page after account delete

Tags: rules, redirection

I have this situation that I need to redirect to a certain page (internal) after the delete of account of user.

I tried using [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) but it isn't working, also tried using `$form_state['redirect']` but still **FAILED**.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you use form_alter for the user deletion page? If so you can add a additional submit handler there and use $form_state['redirect']. Check whether the submit handlers in the form have already used redirect or drupal_goto. If they have used any, then you might need to remove those submit handlers and write a custom one.

Comment: "***... it isn't working ...***" is about the toughest support question to answer. If you really want an answer, then please include an export of your rule to show **what** is not working ...

Comment: form $form_state['redirect'] does not work when you have form rebuild  , did you try implementing hook_delete_user